# Insert CDATA into an XML

Tags: php, xml, regex

I'm in a real hurry right now, and I'm begging REGEX masters for help!
I'm receiving an XML trough a HTTP request, and I just can't parse it since it contains some special chars not being wrapped in CDATA sections.

example XML:

```
<root>
    <node>good node</node>
    <node>bad node containing &</node>
<root>
```

Trying to parse this XML with `simplexml_load_string($xml)` I get:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]:
Entity: line 3: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name in /..../file.php on line ##
```

Supposing that the bad nodes will not contain `>` or `<`, I need a REGEX that will wrap the text in that nodes in CDATA  sections. I guess there will be some lookarounds, I just can't do it quickly.

Thank you!

Comment: Easy: `$result = "<![CDATA[" . $get_file_contents() . "]]>";` No need for a regex!

Comment: So, you don't have any way to get that "XML" (read: "INVALID XML") to have encoded entities?

Comment: Unfortunatly I have no access to that computers, so I can't do anything to get it right for the moment

Comment: @Kerrek: I should wrap the contents of each terminal non-empty node. Your solution will return me the entire xml tree as text - impossible to parse

Comment: @s3v3n: Would it be an option *only* to find stray ampersands and replace them by an entity reference?

Comment: @KerrekSB certainly seems feasible from what I read, and would remedy the mixed-ampersands-and-entities situation that might arise at certain times...

Comment: @KerrekSB The problem is I'm not sure the only special chars will be the ampersands, so I preferred a REGEX solution. The ampersand was only an example and was the first problem I met.

Comment: @s3v3n: In that case I don't think you'll get a truly correct solution unless you run some sort of validating parser that can recover from errors and handle the erroneous section.

Comment: Or accept it as a temporary solution, and ask that guys to give me as quickly as possible a valid XML. :) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can indeed assume that there will be no `<` or `>` characters inside the nodes you want to CDATA-ize, then this should work just fine for your situation:

```
>(?=[^<&]*&)([^<]*)<
```

replacing with

```
<!CDATA[\1]]>
```

This expression only looks for nodes that contain `&` characters (whether or not they are part of HTML entities), then wraps the contents of those nodes in a CDATA tag, if you need to ignore `&` characters inside entities, that's a considerable bit tougher, but I'd be willing to give it a look.

Comment: [A portal to another world will open and from it horrors whose names could not be spoken shall spew forth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). But a pretty nice solution nonetheless.

Comment: it might work - mostly - kinda - with a few exceptions I haven't identified yet... :D

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help! I modified it a little and it worked with a `+` instead of the first `*` because it was matching `<root>[the blanks or nothing right here]<node>`. It's not the perfect solution (as @G_H pointed by providing "the proof"), but it worked for my particular case. I will kindly ask that guys to give me a better, valid XML. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @s3v3n I never say never... No matter how much people scream that something is an anti-pattern or the worst possible solution, you can almost always come up with some case where it's actually right. If this works for you, say, 99.9% of the time and that's good enough, why not? But you should certainly demand that valid XML is provided.