# XmlDocument.LoadXml() throws an exception of type ComException

Tags: c#, .net, xml, windows-runtime

I'm trying to parse the xml document returned from [this link](http://www.onlinetvrecorder.com/?aktion=epg_export&format=xml&btn_ok=OK&stations=3SAT,ANIXE,ARD&from=30.11.2011&to=30.11.2011) but I get an exception of type `ComException` with the following message:

`Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.`

Here's the code:

```
        try
        {
            //...
            string EPGXML = await DownloadAsync(url);

            var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.LoadXml(EPGXML); //this line throws the exception
            //...rest of the code
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //I get here...
        }
```

Could you please help me why I get this message and how can I fix this? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I'm reading the source of the XML using this function (maybe I'm wrong here and I should do something to get the string in UTF-8, because I don't see the German characters in the string in debug mode (watch window):

```
    private async static Task<string> DownloadPageAsync(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            handler.UseCookies = true;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 10000000;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsString();
            return responseBody;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "error" + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this code running on a (non-main) thread?

Comment: And it's a good idea to mention (tag) when you're using a pre-release version of .NET.

Comment: The link you provided isn't valid XML, although that would normally throw an XmlException. Have you tried loading good XML, though?

Comment: I'm using this in WinRT code for my MetroStyle app. And this code runs async on main thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The XML you provided is not valid, at least that's what Firefox says:

> Erreur d'analyse XML : mal formé
>   Emplacement : http://www.onlinetvrecorder.com/?aktion=epg_export&format=xml&btn_ok=OK&>stations=3SAT,ANIXE,ARD&from=30.11.2011&to=30.11.2011
>   Numéro de ligne 218, Colonne 193 :

(Sorry for the french)

Looking a bit closer, it looks like the parser breaks on the word "Plötzlich", on the character "ö".

You should use CDATA to prevent this:

```
<![CDATA[Your text here can contain special chars]]>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks I realized it just now. So how can I escape invalid chars?

Comment: So how can I achieve this? I mean adding `<![CDATA[`

Comment: Is this xml in your hands, I mean are you mister onlinetvrecorder.com?

Comment: I think the best would be to pre-parse the xml string, adding the CDATA where required prior to load in XmlDocument.

Comment: Very strange encoding.  Certainly not 8859-1 as the header promises.

Comment: Could you provide me a little code? I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: I'm a regex illiterate, sorry :)
but I suggest you to read this post, the issue, and provided solution, are very similar to your case.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169684/insert-cdata-into-an-xml)

Comment: Yeah, mismatch in codifications, because ö is a valid character and it shouldn't need <![CDATA[]]>

Answer (score 3):

Do not try to load an XML Document with an html page. Use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) which was meant to do so.

**EDIT**: If you just want the source of the page as a string this should do the trick.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8331002");
request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string data = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    data = reader.ReadToEnd();

Console.WriteLine(data);
```

Comment: The project that I'm working on is on WinRT so I cant *easily* add a reference to .Net assemblies.

Comment: ok, but my suggestion not to load html on an XML Document still applies :)

Comment: Are you sure you can't use Html Agility Pack? I suspect that you could download the source, try compiling it as a WinRT dll, make a few small tweaks, and you'd have a WinRT dll ready for use.