# Download a webpage in UTF-8

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8

I'm using the code below to download [this XML file](http://www.onlinetvrecorder.com/?aktion=epg_export&format=xml&btn_ok=OK&stations=3SAT,ANIXE,ARD&from=30.11.2011&to=30.11.2011):

```
private async static Task<string> DownloadPageAsync(string url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        handler.UseCookies = true;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 10000000;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsString();
        return responseBody;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "error" + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

but the document I'm getting seems to have encoding problems. Although the document is not well formatted, I'm guessing my downloaded webpage is not in UTF-8 either. How can I return a UTF-8 string? Thanks.

Comment: The XML file you are trying to process seems to be invalid. It claims to use iso-8859-1 encoding but in the description of "Farscape" it uses a different encoding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XmlDocument.LoadXml() throws an exception of type ComException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330619/xmldocument-loadxml-throws-an-exception-of-type-comexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your link encoding is **iso-8859-1**.

use

**XmlDocument.Load**(uriString)

or

**XDocument.Load**(uriString)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to download and parse the document for you - it will automatically detect the encoding (where possible), so this shouldn't be a problem for you.

If this is not an option, you need to know what encoding the document is using then transform it to UTF8 using the [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) classes to convert from the original encoding to UTF8.